# Change bg color of carousel on image change

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, background, carousel

(Sorry for my english)

I want to change my slideshow background css with javascript forexample when slideshow shows the second image.

Here is my page link: http://2013.original-k9.de/index.php/julius-k9-kontakt/valami

And the source code:

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
<ol class="carousel-indicators" style="list-style: none;">
    <li class="active" data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
</ol>
<!-- Carousel items -->
<div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="active item"><img src="images/headers/3_14.jpg" alt="3 14" />
    </div>
    <div class="item"><img src="images/headers/3.jpg" alt="3" />
    </div>
</div>
<!-- Carousel nav --><a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data- slide="prev">‹</a><a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-   slide="next">›</a>
</div>
<!-- Call Carousel -->
<script type="text/javascript">
// <![CDATA[
(function($) {
    $('.carousel').carousel({});
})(jQuery);
// ]]>

</script>
```

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 2):

you also can do it at old style like this:

```
function setColor(element, color)
{
    element.style.backgroundColor = color;
}
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
  $(this).css({'background-color': '#ccc'});
  $('a', this).css({'color': 'red'});
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want is something like the following

```
$('#your-element').css('background-color', '#cccccc');
```

Where and how to apply depends on your slider...

You could, for instance, do this inside the carousel functionality, or change the color using `setInterval` etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery to change css properties:

```
$('#element_ID_whose_css_should_be_changed').css({'property_you_want_to_set_or_change' : 'new_value_for_property'});
```

(This can used for altering background-related css properties)